# Yii + phpexcel?

Tags: yii, phpexcel

пытаюсь подружить эти две системы
закинул в

```
...\protected\vendor\PHPExcel\
                                PHPExcel.php
                                PHPExcel\...
                                         all files php
```

в ...\index.php

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config = dirname(__FILE__) . '/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL', 3);

require_once($yii);
//Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();

$app = Yii::createWebApplication($config);
// adding PHPExcel autoloader
Yii::import('application.vendor.*');
require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php";
require_once "PHPExcel/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php";
Yii::registerAutoloader(array('PHPExcel_Autoloader', 'Load'), true);
$app->run();
```

получаю

```
include(PHPExcel_Shared_String.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

хотя файл `...\protected\vendor\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Shared\String.php`
существует

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то тут надо разбираться в том, что происходит. Когда мы объявляем папку в yii через импорт, мы говорим: ищи в этой папке файлы классов, соответствущие названиям классов. Я просто процитирую:

> include(PHPExcel_Shared_String.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   хотя файл ...\protected\vendor\PHPExcel\PHPExcel\Shared\String.php существует

Файла `PHPExcel_Shared_String.php` действительно не существует. Существует `PHPExcel\Shared\String.php`.

Что с этим делать и как бороться? Судя по папке vendor, вы ставите все через composer. В этом случае вам вообще стоит выкинуть автозагрузчик Yii для всего, что с ним не связано - в `index.php` в первых строчках надо подключить `vendor/autoload.php` (иначе первым пропишется автозагрузчик Yii, а он сбрендивший и будет убивать скрипт на первом ненайденном классе, не передавая управление дальше). В этом случае больше ничего не надо подключать и PHPExcel будет уже у вас в руках.

По-хорошему вам вообще не нужен Yii 1. Это машина с большим количеством архитектурных косяков, в т.ч. вот таких. Yii 2 вышел уже довольно давно, нет никакого смысла писать на Yii 1. Не говоря уже о других фреймворках, коих великое множество.

Comment: нет не через композер. здесь глядел http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827115/yii-include-php-excel

Comment: @des1roer, проще всего будет подключить композер и забыть о ряде проблем, хотя можно, конечно, решать проблему вручную.